# How to do sorting in dynamodb when having many attributes needed to be sorted

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am using multiple table design in Dynamodb.

“User” Table
-id(partition key),createdAt, updatedAt, email, username, phoneNumber

All attributes are needed to be sorted except id.

It seems there are only secondary indexes capable of doing sorting.

But there are some drawbacks I’m considering.

GSI: since 5 fields are needed to be sorted, 5 GSI tables will be created.
LSI: It needs to be declared when creating tables, but my table is already created.

In this situation, should I choose GSI for my table to do sorting?

Comment: You have no choice as to use GSI only. As you wrote, LSI can only be created on table creation time.

Comment: Just don't use DynamoDB for this kind of access pattern. Your life will be much easier if you use a SQL db.

Comment: While these comments are correct, sometimes it's worth taking a harder look at your access patterns and ask yourself what you're really trying to do.  For example, how useful is sorting by phone number?  Is that really an access pattern your application needs to support, or is searching by phone number a more realistic access pattern?  It's important that you understand your access patterns before diving into DDB.  It may be the case that DDB is not the right solution for your problem.